# Using a JS Variable with .attr()

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, attr

This should be simple - I want to use a javascript variable, 'foo' within the .attr() element as below:

```
$("#readreplytxt_" + msgid).attr("onClick", "readofferclose(foo)");
```

I've tried this:

```
$("#readreplytxt_" + msgid).attr("onClick", "readofferclose("+ foo")");
```

However no joy.

How can  I make this work?

Comment: Why are you trying to do this instead of just calling `.click()`?

Comment: `"readofferclose(" + foo + ")"` But why not just apply `.on("click", function() { })`?

Comment: The console tells you what's wrong with `"readofferclose("+ foo")"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note you are missing "+" sign.

```
$("#readreplytxt_" + msgid).attr("onClick", "readofferclose("+ foo + ")");
```

Answer (score 5):

If you are already using a script to assign the click why not use the [**click()**](http://api.jquery.com/click/) method to bind the event, similar ot this:

```
$("#readreplytxt_" + msgid).click(function(){
    readofferclose(foo);
});
```

It will make your javascript nice and [**unobtrusive**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) too.

Comment: Basically its a hide/show button, so when the function to show the elements is ran it changes the function ran by the button to the hide function, however each of these functions needs the foo variable passed to them.

Comment: +1 This code will create a hidden reference to `foo`, so the function will see the current value when it will eventually be called.

Comment: If you create a new `foo` variable for each element, then this works.

Comment: @Steve_M If you build a hide/show button you maybe will intrested on .toggle() [Documentation Toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: @AaronDigulla: thanks for fixing the missing `function(){}` :)

Comment: @wumm toggle is a great idea - would work a treat, how would I toggle between two div heights though?

Comment: @Steve_M: One approach could be to use 2 classes and use `toggleClass()`. Or you can use `.css("height", "20px")`, changing the value `20px` for what you need.

Comment: @Steve_M you have to use toggleClass()

Comment: @wumm: carefull with `toggle()` for events, it has been deprecated in 1.8 and removed in 1.9 and cause some issues in rare circumstances. Off course if you use 1.8 or less you can freely use it still without the migrate-plugin

Answer (score 1):

Attach an event handler instead:

```
$("#readreplytxt_" + msgid).click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent the default click action
    readofferclose(foo);
});
```